# Bootstrap 4 radio button is moving to left when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I have added radio button in a table using bootstrap 4. Whenever I click on any of the radio button it moves slightly to the left. I have added a GIF below
[image]

The code of one row from the table is given below.

```
<table>
<tr class="" data-id='1'>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Md. Khairul Basar</td>
    <td class="form-inline table_attendance">
         <div class="form-check form-check-radio">
         <label class="form-check-label">
         <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadio" style=" position: relative;"id="exampleRadios1" value="present">
          <span class="form-check-sign"></span>
                Present
           </label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check form-check-radio">
          <label class="form-check-label">
          <input class="form-check-input pull-right" type="radio" 
name="exampleRadio" style=" position: relative;"id="exampleRadios2" 
value="absent">
         <span class="form-check-sign"></span> 
                 Absent
         </label>
       </div>
      </td>
     </tr>
   <table>
```

If you could help me with the code then it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that it does not move, it just simply gets bigger border and visually it looks like it moved. I guess you could solve your problem by adding to your css for the input with type checkbox this css line - `box-sizing: border-box;`

Answer (score 0):

```
   $('input[type="radio"]').css("box-sizing","border-box");
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, you don't need `position: relative` if you don't use any **top/bottom/left/right** or `position` in child element.
The problem is due to your custom add CSS, I assume.

Try using **`box-sizing: border-box;`** It will force the element to be in original size, even if you use additional padding or border.

For clarification: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: I have removed the **position:relative** part and added **box-sizing: border-box** but still not working.